# Dynamic javascript - onclick not visible

Tags: javascript, ajax

I load html & JS code dynamically from webservice. I use prototype update method:

```
 placeholder.update(result.Static.html); // which also include javascript code
```

Immediately after i loaded code, everything works fine:

```
ProRegResetForm();
alert('reset done');
```

however, from control declared as

```
<a href="javascript://" onclick="javascript:ProRegResetForm();" class="au">Reset</a>
```

I am having error: ProRegResetForm is not defined.

SIMPLIFIED TEST CODE (which is also not working):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var defkeyword_ZipCode = 'Zip Code';

</script>
<a href="javascript://" onclick="alert(defkeyword_ZipCode);">test link</a>
```

Comment: Can you give a more complete example of your code?  The problem is most likely in a section of code you are not showing.  It's hard to tell if something happens to the function between your test call and the click event.  Have you tried changing the click event to a different function (possibly "alert") to make sure the click event is firing correctly?

Comment: You NEVER need javascript: in an onclick. That won't fix your problem though.

Comment: It seems that all variables and functions, defined in coming script live in separate namespace.

Comment: Very basic non working sample published. Just to rememeber, this code is inserted in page using prototype.update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was correct to write code like:

```
<a href="javascript://" id="element">test link</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    functoin somethingcomplex() {
bla bla bla
}

    $('element').onclick = function() { somethingcomplex(); }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that your 'simplified test code' did not execute, you likely have a javascript error elsewhere in your code. Javascript code that follows an exception will not execute.

Have you tried examining the script prior to your snippet (as it appears on the client) using Firebug or IE Developer Toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by delimiting the HTML response from the JavaScript with a '^' and inserting them separately.

```
//=============================================================================
function injectJavascript(src)
    {
    var scripts = document.getElementById("scripts");
    var javascriptSrc = document.createElement("script");
    javascriptSrc.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    javascriptSrc.setAttribute("language", "JavaScript1.2");
    javascriptSrc.innerHTML = src;
    scripts.appendChild(javascriptSrc);
    }
//=============================================================================
function insertHtmlAndScript(target)
    {
    if (req.readyState == 4) // 4 == "loaded"
        {
        if (req.status == 200) // 200 == "Ok"
            {
            var resp = req.responseText.split("^");
            div = document.getElementById(target);
            div.innerHTML = resp[0];
            injectJavascript(resp[1]);
            }
        else
            {
            alert("Could not retreive URL:\n" + req.statusText);
            }
        }
    }
//======================================================================
```

The only reason I can think of that this works while your injection does not is that the HTML vs. JavaScript interpretation is threaded such that the JavaScript can not bind properly... but that's just a guess.